# PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 keeping official PHP 7.x

Tags: php5, ubuntu-16.04, php7

I added the Ondrej repository ( http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ ) on a Ubuntu Xenial virtual machine, to add PHP 5.6. It works flawlessy.

I noticed that this repository includes updates to PHP 7.x, but I'd like to keep the official Ubuntu version and **get updates from Ondrej only for PHP 5.x**. Could you help me to filter the repository updates in a correct way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to "Pin" the specific package version:

http://www.jaredlog.com/?p=1820
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

This post specifically describes how you would accomplish this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/814936/163136